# Application Insights - How to set Custom Operation Id

Tags: azure-application-insights

In our current on-prem setup we have 20+ .net core 3.1 API apps (separate ASP.NET Core API Apps). We have started migrating 2 APi app to Azure App Service tagged with a single Application Insights instance.

In On-Prem, we use some other log framework which the rest of the 18 Apps. All these API apps talk to each other and all the logs are tied to some unique_id in on-prem.

Now, for the apis which is in Azure, we need to leverage the same unique_Id and co-relate everything.

In order to achieve it, I started exploring the functionality of setting a same Operation Id for the 2 apps which are hosted in azure.

Created TelemetrInitializer in both the APIs. and if i set Operational Id as shown below in both the APIs, it's works. All the logs are tied to Single Operation Id "12345"

```
      telemetry.Context.Operation.Id = "12345";
```

However, as it is obvious to make the Operation Id to be dynamic, I have changed it to the below in my First API

```
  telemetry.Context.Operation.Id = "CR" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

So, the next challenge is, I need to tie this new Operation Id in my second API's TelemetryInitiializer. In order to achieve that I tried to grab the Request-Id Header in the TelemetryInitializer of 2nd API. It's always NULL.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Praveen Sreeram.

Comment: Can you take a look at what other headers are being set? In particular, I'm wondering if traceparent and tracestate headers are being set. App Insights is transitioning to W3C Trace-Context and that replaces the Request-Id header. If you are getting the new headers and still need the request-id header for any reason, you can still enable it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#enable-w3c-distributed-tracing-support-for-aspnet-core-apps

Comment: Yeah, i even checked on that path. i don't see those traceparent and tracestate headers too..

Comment: I attempted to repro this and did some additional digging. The next question is how you are calling the other API. If you are using a .NET Core HttpClient, correlation headers should be set by the HttpClient and App Insights just consumes that information automatically- no initializer needed.

Comment: Yes, I'm using .NEt Core HttpClient to make the call from 1st API to the 2nd APIs. If I'm changing the Operation Id in the first API then it is not being used by the second API. If i'm not changing, yes, it's working as expected.

Comment: it would be great if you can share the code that you were talking about. I can have a look

Comment: That makes more sense now. Your original question implied you weren't getting the header at all so that's what I've focused on. Activity Ids are read only and are already unique- you don't need to manually set it up that way. The reason why setting it in your initializer isn't working is because App Insights isn't setting the header- it's consuming the one already set by the HttpClient. If you want to set it manually, you could theoretically disable the automatic tracking and set your own headers and send your own dependency telemetry to App Insights, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Actually, Yes, I thought, the way you link two different API is via Headers. That's the reason I focused on that point my question. In fact, i'm able to set Operation Id in my first API. And, I can see that in App Insights timeline too. All I need is to use the same Operation Id in the 2nd API as well. Is that possible?

Comment: If you do nothing the operation id in the 1st and 2nd API should match and the value is passed via the header. The reason why they don't match for you is because you are manually changing the operation id value in the 1st API after the request has already been sent.

Comment: Exactly. in my case, I already use some other tool which has a uniqueId in all my on-prem apps. As we are moving to azure incrementally, we are migrating the very first few apps into azure. So, we need to maintain the co-relation b/w azure apps and with on-prem apps too. So, instead of using the default operation id, can we change it?

Comment: It did require quite a bit of customization, but I have gotten it working- see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tldr: This is possible by disabling the built in dependency tracking in .NET Core and App Insights and handling it on your own. In most cases, the best thing to do is let .NET Core and App Insights do the tracking.

I uploaded a simple WebAPI app with the code I'm going to go over to Github: https://github.com/SamaraSoucy-MSFT/customoperationid

There are two things that need to be overridden to get both the headers and App Insights to get the custom operation Id. The first is the Activity the wraps the HttpClient as that controls the correlation headers. The second is the dependency tracing in App Insights.

It is possible to [disable Actions completely](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19044) in your HttpClients, but to minimize side effects, you can just remove the one in the client by setting `Activity.Current = null`

```
var operationId = "CR" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var url = "https://www.microsoft.com";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var requestMessage =
        new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
    {
        //Makes the headers configurable
        Activity.Current = null;

        //set correlation header manually
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Request-Id", operationId);
        await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    }
}
```

The next step is to remove the App Insights default tracking [for this request](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/456). Again, you can disable dependency tracking completely, or you can [filter out the default telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling) for this request. Processors are registered inside the Startup class just like initializers.

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<CustomFilter>();

public class CustomFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    // next will point to the next TelemetryProcessor in the chain.
    public CustomFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        // To filter out an item, return without calling the next processor.
        if (!OKtoSend(item)) { return; }

        this.Next.Process(item);
    }

    // Example: replace with your own criteria.
    private bool OKtoSend(ITelemetry item)
    {
        var dependency = item as DependencyTelemetry;

        if (dependency == null) return true;

        if (dependency.Type == "Http"
            && dependency.Data.Contains("microsoft.com")
            //This key is just there to help identify the custom tracking
            && !dependency.Context.GlobalProperties.ContainsKey("keep"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally, in the method that makes the remote call, you need to inject a telemetry client and call [`TelemetryClient.TrackDependency()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#manually-tracking-dependencies)

```
var operationId = "CR" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

//setup telemetry client
telemetry.Context.Operation.Id = operationId;
if (!telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.ContainsKey("keep"))
{
    telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("keep", "true");
}
var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
//continue setting up context if needed

var url = "https:microsoft.com";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    //Makes the headers configurable
    Activity.Current = null;

    using (var requestMessage =
        new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
    {
        //Makes the headers configurable
        Activity.Current = null;

        //set header manually
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Request-Id", operationId);
        await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    }
}

//send custom telemetry 
telemetry.TrackDependency("Http", url, "myCall", startTime, timer.Elapsed, true);
```